# The return type '_MainPage' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

I create page with bottom_nav_bar, but now i cant open it in emulator, bcs error Error: A value of type '_MainPage' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.

Problem here:          `'/Main': (BuildContext context) => _MainPage(),`

Here code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LogInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Log In")),
      body: Center(
          child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Main');
              },
              child: Text("Log In")),
          RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/LogIn/Registr');
              },
              child: Text("Registration")),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

class QRCodePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("QR Scan")),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Main');
              },
              child: Text("Scan")),
        ));
  }
}

class RegistrPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Registration")),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Main');
              },
              child: Text("Log In")),
        ));
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPage createState() => _MainPage();
}

class _MainPage extends State<MyApp> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Main")),
      body: Container(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.restaurant_menu), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        ],
      onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
      },
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main()
{
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/LogIn',
    routes: {
      '/LogIn': (BuildContext context) => LogInPage(),
      '/QRScan': (BuildContext context) => QRCodePage(),
      '/LogIn/Registr': (BuildContext context) => RegistrPage(),
      '/Main': (BuildContext context) => _MainPage(),
    },
  ));
}
```

Comment: well main page is not a widget, use the name that ends with StatelessWidget or stateFul widget.

Comment: If i set StatelessWidget or StatefulWidget, then navigation between icons in bottom_nav_bar dont work bcs we dont have setState method in StatelessWidget or StatefulWidge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `MyApp` instead of `_MainPage`? `_MainPage` is not the Widget but the State.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/Main',
    routes: {
      '/LogIn': (BuildContext context) => LogInPage(),
      '/QRScan': (BuildContext context) => QRCodePage(),
      '/LogIn/Registr': (BuildContext context) => RegistrPage(),
      '/Main': (BuildContext context) => MyApp(),
    },
  ));
}
```

You should probably rename `MyApp` into `MainPage` for more clarity.

Also, you have to define the `label` or `title` of each `BottomNavigationBarItem`:

```
items: [
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    label: 'Home',
    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue
  ),
  ...
],
```